# How to access the parent view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I am using this code to push a view controller in `ViewControllerA`:

```
DatePickerViewController *viewController = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DatePickerViewController" bundle:nil];
NSMutableArray *info = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Exam Duration",nil];
[viewController setInfo:info];
[info release];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

In the `DatePickerViewController` that is slid in, it has a text field. In `ViewControllerA` how can I get the value of this text field once the `viewWillDisappear` method is fired, it's to save data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Best would be to use a delegate pattern or a notification system.

Which one you choose depends on your whishes. If you just want the 'parent controller' to know about the value, use a delegate method.

Using delegates or notifications creates a loosely coupled structure and makes reusable classes possible.

**EDIT: Some sample code. Beware: untested and from the top of my head!**

*DatePickerViewController.h*

```
@protocol DatePickerViewControllerDelegate
    -(void)datePicker:(DatePickerViewController *)picker pickedDate:(NSDate *)date;
@end
```

*DatePickerViewController.m*

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.delegate datePicker:self pickedDate:theDate]; //Delegate is an ivar
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

*ViewControllerA.m*

```
//
DatePickerViewController *viewController = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DatePickerViewController" bundle:nil];
NSMutableArray *info = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Exam Duration",nil];
[viewController setInfo:info];
[info release];
[viewController setDelegate:self]; // Set the delegate of the date picker
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
//

-(void)datePicker:(DatePickerViewController *)picker pickedDate:(NSDate *)date; {
     //Deal with the new date here
}
```

Comment: What do you mean // Delegate is an ivar?

Comment: Ivar means 'instance variable'. DatePickerViewController has an instance variable `id delegate`. In this sample it's also an property: `@property(assign) id delegate`